# Regular expression removing elements between comma and semi column and respecting the order

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text my_text= `"Volberda, Henk W.; Van Den Bosch, Frans A.J.; Mihalache, Oli R."`
I would like the get only the last names  i.e. `Volberda, Van Den Bosch, Mihalache,`
I tried something like this:

```
import re
lastnames = re.sub(', [^>]+;', '', my_text)
```

but I got

```
Volberda Mihalache, Oli R.
```

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Looks like string methods should suffice here:

```
[i.split(',')[0].strip() for i in my_text.split(';')]
# ['Volberda', 'Van Den Bosch', 'Mihalache']
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `[^>]+` you are matching any character except `>`

You might instead match any character except `;` or `,` and use a positive lookbehind `(?<=,)` to keep the comma in the output.

```
(?<=,) [^;,]+(?:;|$)
```

- `(?<=,)`  Positive lookbehind, assert a `,` on the left and match a space
- `[^;,]+` Match 1 times any char except `;` or `,`
- `(?:;|$)` Match either `;` or assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mw7Jug/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sc0fsF)

```
import re
my_text= "Volberda, Henk W.; Van Den Bosch, Frans A.J.; Mihalache, Oli R."
lastnames = re.sub(r'(?<=,) [^;,]+(?:;|$)', '', my_text)
print(lastnames)
```

Output

```
Volberda, Van Den Bosch, Mihalache,
```